# PHP Run scripts without the need of a browser window to be open

Tags: php

I'd like to know whether it is possible to have PHP run commands on a set loop, without the need of a user to be actively viewing it on a browser.

For example, mail sending - I'd like to be able to have this loop run, even when I close the browser, until I command it to stop.

```
$name = "Foo";
$to = $row['email'] //imagine it was fetched from a database;
mail($to,"Hello ".$name."! you won a million dollars!","Just kidding!");
```

After looking it up, I've noticed that some people mentioned it is possible to run PHP scripts as processes,
I'd love to know if such a thing can be done, and if so I'd appreciate any help regarding the case

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, the name of it is `CLI` what means, `command line interface`. Just simply run: `php.exe myfile.php`

Comment: Do you have to run it like that from the console? because I intended to even be able to start the loop from within a PHP script

Comment: Yes, you can run it from console. On *nix system, you can send it to the background also.

Comment: What system are you on Windows or Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a queue manager like rabbitmq or beanstalk.

http://www.rabbitmq.com/

http://beanstalkapp.com/

or you can set tasks with cron.

[How to create cron job using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php)

Comment: With cron, is it possible to have a few tasks running simultaneously?